# Savings a DocRaptor response to Firebase storage inside a callable Firebase Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to send a template to [DocRaptor](https://docraptor.com/documentation/node) and then get a pdf back and save that in a Firebase Storage location. My issue is that DocRaptor returns binary data for the PDF rather than something like a link to the pdf. I'm trying to convert this to a buffer to save in storage, however, when it saves the file, it saves it as application/octet-stream type instead of application/pdf.

```
/* DOCRAPTOR PDF GENERATOR */
export const createPdfFile = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const config = {
    url: 'https://docraptor.com/docs',
    encoding: null,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    },
    json: {
      user_credentials: docRaptorKey,
      doc: {
        document_content: data.content,
        type: "pdf",
        test: sandboxMode
      }
    }
  }
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    requestModule.post(config, (err, response, body) => {
      if(!err) {
        let buffer = new Buffer(body, "binary");
        bucket.file(data.path).save(buffer).then((results) => {
          resolve(response);
        }).catch((error) => {
          reject(error);
        });
      } else {
        reject(err);
      }
    });
  }).then((response) => {
    return {'results':response}
  }).catch((error) => {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', error);
  });
});
```

Comment: If you want to set the content type on a file upload to Cloud Storage, you should be specifying that yourself in the object metadata.  https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#content-type

Comment: @DougStevenson will that actually create a readable PDF though? Isn't that just saving it as a file type? Genuine question...

Comment: @DougStevenson, that would be a no. I just tried it. It only changed the application type.

Comment: DocRaptor employee here. Our asynchronous generation method returns a URL, not a binary file. You could try using that instead.

Comment: @jamespaden thank you but I’ve sense dropped docraptor and actually just use html-pdf library now.